# Is it possible to stop association of additional modifications to a work item after it is marked as 'resolved' in TFS 2015?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We are working on TFS 2015 and Visual Studio 2015.

**Query:**
Is it possible to stop association of code check-in to a work item after it is marked as 'resolved' in TFS 2015?

In a custom work item workflow, we want NO change against a work item once QA approves the work item for production movement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This boils down to a user discipline issue.

You can enforce it within Visual Studio (and *only* within Visual Studio) via a custom check-in policy, but check-in policies are relatively easy to circumvent and definitely will not cover every scenario.